# How to use d3.max() with an associative array

Tags: d3.js

If I want the maximum value of an array, I can do this:

```
var data = [1,2,3,4,5];
console.log(d3.max(data));             //output 5
```

But if I try with an associative array, I get 'undefined':

```
var data = {'foo' : 4, 'baz' : 8};
console.log(d3.max(data));             //output undefined
```

**How do I use d3.max() with an associative array?**

Comment: Those functions only work on arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on help from the comments to the question, this was the solution:

```
 d3.max(d3.values(data));
```